# Creating multiple config files with chef on a Vagrant VM using Dir and File Ruby classes

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

So I am creating a VM with vagrant and provision it with chef-client. On a certain step it should look through a directory and create files from .erb templates (around 50 of them).

This is the recipe:

```
puts("Configuring app...")
Dir.glob('/opt/app/conf/**/*.erb').each do |conf_file|
  conf_file_name = File.basename(conf_file, ".erb")
  conf_file_loc = File.dirname(conf_file)
    template "#{conf_file_loc}/#{conf_file_name}" do
      local true
      source "#{conf_file}"
      action :create
  end
end
```

So what it does is look for each .erb file in conf directory and in it's child directories, cut of .erb from their name and create a file based on the template.

This code works, I've run it on a manually created VirtualBox VM and had no problem, but when using chef-client provisioning on the Vagrant generated VM this recipe seems to just get skipped. No error messages, no warnings, no logs - nothing. All there is are untouched templates in /opt/app/conf. I can't even see "Configuring app..." string in vagrant output.

I can't use chef-solo provisioning since the same recipe is used for generating both QA environment on our cloud server and a local environment for the devs and I want all of them to be provisioned by our chef server.

Is there any way I could fix it or at least some kind of a logging feature that is not debug level logging for chef?

Vagrant and VBox are on Windows7 machine and I am using chef/centos6.5 box.

Comment: Maybe the content of the vagrantfile may help finding your problem (with your cookbook name, etc) A log of the chef run would be of some help too

Comment: That log didn't mention this recipe at all. Anyway, I'm posting the solution right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're hit by the compile/converge problem. See http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html

But maybe you're just no having the recipe in your runlist.

If its the first case here is an explanation:

Your `Dir.Glob()` is done at compile time, at this time your `remote_directory` (or whatever) creating the templates has not run and the dir is empty.

Easy solution: two run of chef, the second would find the files and create the `template` resources for each.

Another option would be to encapsulate your code inside a `ruby_block` so your code will be evaluated at converge time and should work.

Comment: Yes, seems that was the case. Encapsulating the recipe in to a ruby_block did help. It's still strange that everything worked on a manually created VM.

Comment: Without knowing how you did it on a manually created VM and without knowing how the templates are put in the directories its hard to diagnose and help on this point ...

Comment: I simply used knife to bootstrap the VM, then assigned roles and recipes manually with chef-server web gui and that's it. Run lists for both manual and Vagrant VMs are completely identical. However that's the difference: manually assigning run list after a bootstrap and creating the run list with Vagrant file.

Comment: @DramaLama Maybe there's a typo in your vagrant file on the `add_recipe` part, a bad entry in the runlist would have fail the chef-client run on `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision`. I can only see a two chef run to complete your original code (still assuming the .erb are put in place by chef too). Tell me if you want to dig deeper on the subject or not ;)

Comment: Files are being put by chef with cookbook_file and a bash script for unziping. This recipe comes after on the run list and does template configuration. I'm still new to DevOps or IT for that matter (radio-engineering degree) so I still have a lot to learn. I will dig in to chef and ruby docs and related books. For now this solution is sufficient, I shall show it to my senior colleagues and perhaps incorporate it somehow in to our internal trainings.

Comment: @DramaLama From what you tell, you may take advantage of [artifact cookbook](https://github.com/riotgames/artifact-cookbook) or [ark cookbook](https://github.com/burtlo/ark), which gives you some free control on what to do to end the configuration from an artifact (one or more zip file in your case), the callbacks would be executed after the unzip, and so you don't need the class instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Tensibai was spot on the problem - putting the recipe inside a ruby_block solved the issue.

Here is how I edited the recipe:

```
ruby_block "Create configs for #{node['hostname']}" do
  action :create
  block do
    Dir.glob('opt/app/conf/**/*.erb').each do |conf_file|
      conf_file_name = File.basename(conf_file, ".erb")
      conf_file_loc = File.dirname(conf_file)
        t=Chef::Resource::File::Template.new("#{conf_file_loc}/#{conf_file_name}", run_context)
        t.local true
        t.source conf_file
        t.owner 'user'
        t.group 'root'
        t.run_action :create
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you very much, you just made at least 40 lazy developers and testers very happy.

Comment: It leaves me with a 'code smell' feeling, I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it, but without more insight on the whole picture its hard to guess what would fit your problem.